# How to restore PrestaShop 1.4.3 start page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, prestashop

I'm trying to repair old PrestaShop 1.4.3, the start page on web site has been maliciously removed and replaced, the rest pages are OK, not touched. How to restore start page? I only have html copy of start page from Google cache. No backup available, so don't suggest me restore from backup.

Comment: this might work on latest Prestashop versions, not on PrestaShop 1.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [this link](https://www.prestashop.com/en/developers-versions#previous-version) and download your PrestaShop version, copy and paste the index.php and init.php files on your server.
I guess that it works.

EDIT:
If you refer to the templates files (the .tpl), I think there isn't a solution, only restore from a previous backup (that you haven't).